# How you pass a named method to the fallback route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

In Laravel routing there is fallback method:

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

A normal route is somethig like this:

```php
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@list');
```

There is a way to use the fallback route like this:

```php
Route::fallback('FallbackController@index');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You answered your own question?

https://twitter.com/themsaid/status/910135205989625856/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E910135205989625856&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Flaravel-news.com%2Flaravel-v5-5-5

```
Route::fallback('FallbackController@index');
```

Is indeed the syntax (Laravel 5.5.5+).

Comment: Interestingly, they haven't mentioned that in their [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#fallback-routes).

Answer (score 0):

For new versions of Laravel, try:

```
Route::fallback([FallbackController::class, 'index']);
```